# Jekyll Error upon serve or build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, syntax-error, jekyll, rvm

Getting an error every time I attempt to use jekyll build/ jekyll serve on v3.1.6 on Mac High Sierra. I have attempted a gem clean up bundle install uninstalling and re-installing jekyll. Does anyone have any sort of imput on this?

```
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054: warning: else without rescue 
is useless
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060: warning: else without rescue 
is useless
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2099: warning: else without rescue 
is useless
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script.rb:34:in `require': 
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2050: syntax error, unexpected 
modifier_if (SyntaxError)
      if separator.value == 'auto'
        ^
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054: syntax error, unexpected 
',', expecting keyword_end
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060: syntax error, unexpected 
')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/alexandermurray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sass-
3.5.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2095: syntax error, unexpected 
modifier_if
      if separator.value == 'auto'
        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like sass-3.5.2 is not compatible with ruby-2.1.3. You need to update the version of Ruby. The problem could be related to this issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10279.